# Calendar .YEAR, .MONTH, DAY_OF_MONTH different than date.getDay() etc?

Tags: java, android, datetime, ormlite

I realized this:

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
mYear=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
mMonth=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
mDay=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

And this:

```
Date d = c.getTime();
int day = d.getDay();
int month = d.getMonth();
int year= d.getYear();
```

Yield different numbers, is there some initialization I am missing?  I care because I am using ORMLite and trying to store dates into a database, which is a Date object, but Date is being deprecated and so I am trying now to use Calendar but it doesn't seem that simple since the above code results in different answers for the day, month, and year.

Comment: Im curious, what values are you getting for both?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the `Date.getYear(), getMonth() and getDay()` are deprecated and specifically ask you to use Calendar.get()

The reason why you are getting different answers is two-fold

`getDay()` returns the day of the week and not the date -- use `getDate()` here

`getYear()` returns year - 1900

Here is the relevant note from the API documentation

**Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900.**

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getYear%28%29

Comment: Maybe there is also problem with timezone and DST - they may be differently handled by Calendar and Date.

Comment: Indeed great answer, but now I am curious about something...what about Date fields in databases ?  That ORMLite i just got working on android great and its pretty awesome, but dealing with the date fields is not very fun.  Should I just make longs and store the time in millis there and then write some utility for displaying dates but always store those millis?

Comment: @Codejoy -- not familiar with ORMLite .. but storing dates as dates makes more sense to me. If you store them as millis, you might have trouble querying them later ( or even making sense of them ).